# Will home networks migrate to ipv6?

Tags: ipv4, ipv6, ip, ipv6-transition

So I have a rudimentary understanding of working with basic networking tools, things like using `nmap` to scan ports and find IP addresses on internal networks, and `ssh` for connecting to various devices. I am a bit confused about how all of this will change with the transition from IPv4 to IPv6. I understand that IPv6 addresses will look something like this:

```
FE80:0000:0000:0000:0202:B3FF:FE1E:8329
```

which seems a lot longer than IPv4 addresses like:

```
202.202.0.113
```

although IPv6 addresses can be collapsed by using the `::` to represent two to eight contiguous blocks of zeroes.

The architecture change from IPv4 to IPv6 is obviously unavoidable for the global internet to continue to function, but will internal networks (like the familiar `192.168.x.x` addresses in most home routers) transition to IPv6 alongside the rest of the internet, or are internal networks more likely to stick with IPv4, and have the network translate outgoing and incoming packets between IPv4 and IPv6?

Comment: It's a decent question in general but home networking questions are considered off-topic here. Maybe you can get it migrated to PowerUser.SE.

Comment: Many ISPs are assigning IPv6 alongside IPv4 to consumers. Most new home routers support IPv6. Almost all new consumer products and OSes support IPv6. IPv6 is running alongside IPv4 in many homes, and it will eventually become the dominant IP protocol.  ARIN is down to less than 128K IPv4 addresses available to assign with requests for much more than that, so it will run out of IPv4 addresses in a few weeks.

Comment: This is an interesting question, but I think there's no objective answer, so I'm voting to close as opinion-based.

Comment: Perhaps I should rephrase it as "Is it technically feasible for home internal networks to stay with ipv4 as the rest of the internet goes to ipv6?"

Comment: The short answer to that question is Yes, but I suspect that's not what you're really asking.  Your tools and such will operate the same with IPv4 and IPv6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Home networks and mobile devices are usually the first to get IPv6.

This is because the devices running those networks are often provided and managed by the ISP. ISPs use lots of IPv4 addresses so they feel the pain of running out. They will need to share IPv4 addresses (NAT, CGN) between their customers to be able to provide connectivity.

Those big central NAT boxes are expensive, and by providing IPv6 as well as IPv4+NAT they can lower the load on those NAT boxes and reduce their dependency on them. That will lower their cost so they have an incentive to provide IPv6.

Translating outgoing connections from IPv4 devices to IPv6 servers on the internet isn't possible either. An IPv6 address is 128 bits long, an IPv4 address only 32 bits. An IPv4 connection therefore only has 32 bits to use as the destination, and there is no way fit in all possible IPv6 destinations.

The other way around does work, and is used in many mobile networks. Every device get IPv6-only connectivity and the DNS server for that network puts the 32 bits of IPv4 destinations inside a special block of 128 bit IPv6 addresses. The client connects to that IPv6 address and a special NAT box in the network recognises the special block, extracts the original 32 bit IPv4 destination address, and makes the IPv4 connection.

So keeping home and mobile clients on IPv4-only won't work. Making them IPv6-only can work in specific cases like mobile devices. Unfortunately there are still some devices that need IPv4 in a home (not that many really. PCs, tablets, phones and printers are usually fine without IPv4, but e.g. game consoles like the PS3, PS4, Wii and Wii-U currently still need IPv4) so IPv4 will be around for a little while longer.

So home networks will be among the first to get IPv6 next to IPv4, mostly to keep the IPv4 cost down and to avoid performance and dependency problems with large scale NAT devices inside the ISP network. IPv4 will start disappearing in homes once the last devices like game consoles update their firmware to add IPv6 support. Mobile networks have already dropped IPv4 connectivity to the device and make it possible to connect to IPv4-only destinations with a DNS64+NAT64 setup.

PS: The Xbox One is the happy exception on the home network. It is built completely around IPv6 and will use backward-compatibility tricks to work on network with just IPv4.

Comment: DNS resolvers would be the first to get IPv6, just saying :)